# Philadelphia, Pa. voting machine

Tags: united-states, election

When I went in to vote today, I signed the book and I was asked to wait a minute while the girl called over a gentleman.  The man came over and did something to the back of the voting machine.  What was he doing?  It looked like he either pressed a button or adjusted something.  Is this a normal procedure after each person votes?

Comment: Did you notice anything different about the machine after the man came over to fiddle with it? Could it have been something as simple as an on/off switch?

Comment: There are many different kinds of election machines.  If you are concerned, call the elections board and ask.  Not so much that it is likely that something was wrong, but that you have the right to know how the machine that counts your vote works.

Comment: The machines where I vote ALWAYS have someone go and adjust something before anyone goes vote. No idea what, but it clearly seems like SOP

Answer (score 4):

Philadelphia used the [Danaher Shouptronic 1242](https://www.verifiedvoting.org/resources/voting-equipment/danaher/shouptronic/) this year. The process is (emphasis mine):

> Voting Process: When voters enter the precinct, poll workers confirm that they are properly registered to vote. **The poll worker uses an operator’s panel on the back of the machine to choose the ballot style appropriate for that voter.** The voter enters the curtains (see pictures at left above) and only the races for which they are permitted to vote are activated. The voter then votes by pressing a numbered box beside each choice in each race on the ballot.

So most likely, since (AFAIK) there wouldn't be any differences in ballot within a polling place, the poll worker just pushed the "activate" button. By making a worker push it between voters, it prevents someone from casting their vote and then immediately casting another (and another...) until the poll workers removed them.